# Emacs desktop-save-mode startup error

Tags: emacs, desktop

After adding the following code in my .emacs file, comes up some error during startup of emacs. I am a newbie of emacs, is there some one can help me figure out where are the errors come from?

**Added code in .emacs:**

```
;; Auto-saving the Desktop
(require 'desktop)
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(defun my-desktop-save ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Don't call desktop-save-in-desktop-dir, as it prints a message.
  (if (eq (desktop-owner) (emacs-pid))
      (desktop-save desktop-dirname)))
(add-hook 'auto-save-hook 'my-desktop-save)
```

**Errors:**
[image]

Comment: What is the error? Please edit you question, it seems incomplete.

Comment: I added your code to my init file and don't receive any errors on startup or close. From the looks of the error file you've specified I'd guess that it is in some way connected to EDE, have you tried this without loading ede (or any part of cedet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the function definition](http://code.google.com/p/dea/source/browse/trunk/lisps/cedet/contrib/ede-gnustep.el?r=749#480) for what's breaking, it seems that the error is that prj-file is `NIL` in line 492. (The other `expand-filename` call in the function shouldn't ever have a nil, since it's the car of a non-nil list of filenames).

Now, `prj-file` is the first filename in `/home/shenyan/Test/memcached-1.4.11` matching the regexp `"\\(Root\\)?ProjStep.ede"` and presumably there isn't one. Since memcached presumably doesn't have an EDE project file, what's gone wrong must be that line 508's call to ede-project-p did something weird when called with this subdirectory of `/home/shenyan/Test/`.

I can't work out exactly why that happened, but you can debug things quite easily. First bring up your `*scratch*` buffer to type emacs lisp easily. To check my guess, insert the following code into the buffer

```
(ede-directory-project-p "/home/shenyan/Test/memcached-1.4.11")
```

and run it by hitting `C-x C-e` with cursor on the closing bracket. If it returns `nil` I was wrong. Otherwise, you've found the culprit and should probably debug it further by hunting through the bits of `ede-directory-project-p` in [ede-files.el](http://code.google.com/p/dea/source/browse/trunk/lisps/cedet/ede/ede-files.el?r=749).

Probably what's going on is that your `/home/shenyan/Test/` directory has something that tells EDE to search subdirectories (or maybe that's the default?) and then the memcached subdirectory has a file whose name makes EDE think it should be searched for a project file. If you work out exactly what happened, you might consider submitting a bug to the EDE developers: they probably shouldn't error out if the project file doesn't exist.

Comment: Note that, according to [http://www.randomsample.de/cedetdocs/ede/ede/Detecting-a-Project.html], you can stop EDE falling over by adding a file `.ede-ignore` in your memcached directory, but I guess it would be nice to fix things properly.